# Global beforeAll in Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I need to simulate different window sizes in my tests using React Testing Library and Jest.

Currently I'm having to have this `beforeAll` in every test file:

```
import matchMediaPolyfill from 'mq-polyfill';

beforeAll(() => {
  matchMediaPolyfill(window)
  window.resizeTo = function resizeTo(width, height) {
    Object.assign(this, {
      innerWidth: width,
      innerHeight: height,
      outerWidth: width,
      outerHeight: height,
    }).dispatchEvent(new this.Event('resize'))
  }
})
```

Which I use like so:

```
it('does something at small screen sizes', async () => {
  window.resizeTo(320, 800);
  // actual test here
```

Can I have a global `beforeAll` that will apply to every test file in my project?

The docs mention `globalsetup`:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globalsetup-string

However it errors as it doenst recognise the `beforeAll` function. I seemed to me that that option is meant for setting up an environment but not adding something to the test files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`globalSetup` runs in another process and cannot access [`beforeAll`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globalsetup-string) or other variables from test scope. It's meant for initializations made before any test is started, e.g. setting up a server, like the documentation shows.

It's `setupFiles` that runs in test process. `beforeAll` should be executed after Jest environment is initialized, so it should be moved to [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array).

Comment: if i just want to initialize the database once for all tests, it setupFilesAfterEnv still the place to put ? Doc says "In other words, setupFilesAfterEnv modules are meant for code which is repeating in each test file."

Comment: No, it's globalSetup, there's an example for that in docs