# Jest database setup before any test suits are run

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, ts-jest

I'm trying to seed my entire database for all the necessary resources that need to be present to test my API successfully. My tests are in several files.

How can I achieve this such that the database will completely be seeded before one test from any suite runs?

I'm trying to achieve this without using `beforeAll` and `afterAll` as shown in Jest docs. I want to do the entire seeding before every single one of the test files.

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Realized I left out a key part of the question.  See above.  Want to do it without specifying a `beforeAll` `afterAll` as that is specific per test file and I need to have a way that ensures every resource that would potentially be used is already seeded as I can't ensure the order in which the individual tests will run

Comment: You still can use before/afterAll: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65738804/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess my confusion is with `beforeAll` then.  To my understanding specifying `beforeAll` will run once before every test is run.  I'm more so looking for something that "runs once in total before all tests are run".  Am I mistaking the function of `beforeAll`?  

Either way it seems I can use `setupFiles` and `setupFilesAfterEnv` to do initial setup logic to satisfy my need.

Comment: The thing that runs before each test is... beforeEach. beforeAll runs before all tests in a given scope.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah that makes sense.  I'll use a combination of setup file and `beforeAll` to achieve this then.  Perfect.   Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out in the way I originally planned using `globalSetup`.

The reason I am using `globalSetup` versus handling this in `beforeAll` / `afterAll` is that I want it to be run once per `npm run test`.  I have several `*.test.ts` files and don't want to seed and then remove all resources before each one.

I have the following `globalSetup` field set in `jest.config.ts`

```
globalSetup: "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/setup/setup.api.ts",
```

`setup.api.ts`:

```
import 'tsconfig-paths/register';
import { seedTestDB } from "./setup.db"
import { setupTestUser } from "./testHelpers"
import { mongoConnect, mongoDisconnect } from "../../server/services/mongo"
import User from "../../models/User"

// // Global setup file used for tests that will complete once before ALL test suites run
const setup = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoConnect()
    // Sign in the user that will be used for Int / E2E testing
    // Also sets the user id for use in seeding logic
    await setupTestUser()

    // Seed database as needed
    // This also handles auto removing stale test resources before seeding
    await seedTestDB()

    // Grant temporary admin access to test account for unit tests to run
    await grantTempAdminAccess(process.env.__TEST_USER_ID__ as string)

    await mongoDisconnect()
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
    await mongoDisconnect()
  }
}

export default setup
```

I connect to my database and then set up the test user that will be used for all test requests to endpoints.  Everything in my API is behind auth middleware.  I then seed that database.  Important to note that before I seed the database I remove any resources that might have been seeded previously.  Doing this at the beginning instead of the end seemed more reliable.  In the end I disconnect from the database.

Comment: How do you share that mongo connection across your test files? From what I read setupGlobals does not let you use variables there in your tests, so I was stuck there.

Comment: I do reinitiate the `mongoConnect` and `mongoDisconnect` functions in relative `beforeAll/afterAll`.  The above functions for global setup was so I could handle seeding the database once before tests run.  I do initiate the connections themselves in each test and then dispose of them once that test is done.  

But it seemed more efficient than seeding separately for my use case to handle that part of the logic in a global setup file.

@DmitriR117